# How to install qt sdk (qt 4.x) by apt-get (the full version)?

Tags: installation, apt, qt

I've installed `QtSdk-offline-linux-x86-v1.2.1` on Ubuntu 12.10 it has some bugs, crashes all the time.

It does not appear in the Ubuntu Software Center and would not upgrade to the new version by `apt-get upgrade`.

How can I install the qt sdk 4.x (the version on Ubuntu repository) by `apt-get` (what command should I use)?

I just want it to be upgradable to new version (when system is getting upgraded) and be completely installed (all libraries are needed just like qt sdk offline installer)

Comment: I guess the Bugs come from Ubuntu 12.10! Switch to 12.04 and you'll be happy :)

Comment: I want install QT 4.x on my ubuntu 12.10 not my QT on ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible by installing following packages

qt-sdk

Qt 4 assistant

Qt creator

Qt 4 designer

Qt 4 inguist